# В файл выводит лишнее повторяющееся значение, которого не должно быть

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++, ввод

Мне нужно чтобы в файл выводило суммы чисел, но выводит число стоящее на последней позиции файла два раза.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long  A, B;
long n = 0;
long sum = 0;
ifstream infile("input.txt");
ofstream outfile("output.txt");
while (infile);
{
    infile >> A >> B;
    

    for ( long  i = A; i <= B; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
        
    }
    outfile << sum << endl;
    cout << sum << endl;
    sum = 0;
        

}
```

}е сюда код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо

```
while (infile);  // Кстати, надеюсь, на самом деле у вас тут точки с запятой нет?...
{
    infile >> A >> B;
```

написать

```
while (infile >> A >> B)
{
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, заработало, перестало выводить лишнее.